# Formatting text in RIA App (considering between Silverlight, AIR & Titanium)

Tags: silverlight, air, titanium

i want to create an app where users can format text, simple formatting just like what the markdown editor here on stack overflow can do, bold, italic, lists etc.

i am really tempted to use a solution like AIR or Titanium where i can use HTML/JS to implement this. however, AIR have [disabled some features](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html) like shadows, @font-face, etc. features that i may not use currently, but i may use in the future. development for titanium desktop seems to have stalled.

Silverlight seems like a possible alternative but to create formatted text i use something like flow document? but i really like Entity Framework & how C# is such a powerful language. i am leaning towards silverlight currently but how can i implement a way to format text. i could have a textbox that users will enter markdown in and use a web browser control to render HTML, that seems like a "bad" way of implementing this? i will have many web browser controls to display HTML parts ?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4 has a RichTextBox. Have you looked into that one? Demo video here: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Diving-into-the-RichTextBox-Silverlight-TV-31/

There are various discussions about on the best way to transform to HTML and back.

If you need something more powerful, there are 3rd party options [like this one.](http://www.vectorlight.net/demos/richtextbox.aspx)